# Wrap a summernote wrappedrange

Tags: summernote

I'm writing some custom code on top of summernote.  I have a summer note WrappedRange which contains several nodes.  I simply want to wrap all of these nodes in a new parent node.  I can't find a method within summernote to do this.  Does it exist, or do I need to write a routine to do this?  How would you accomplish this?

I'm doing the following:

```
var rng = summernote.Range.create();

if(rng.sc !== rng.ec || !summernote.Dom.isText(rng.sc)) {
  rng = rng.expand(summernote.Dom.isPara);
  rng.select();      

  // need to wrap rng in a new DIV tag
  ....
```